# How to add more value on java string array?

Tags: java

I have a listview.

```
private String[] listView2 = {"aa","aa","aa"};
int a = 0;
```

Int values will decide to add the number of content

So if a==2.

```
listView2 = {"aa","aa"};
```

if a==5

```
listView2 = {"aa","aa","aa","aa","aa"};
```

Answer (score 4):

You're clearly familiar with array initializers where you specify the content up-front... but you can also create arrays just by specifying the length, like this:

```
 String[] array = new String[length];
```

This will create an array where every element is a null reference (or the a 0, false or `'\0'` for numeric, Boolean or character arrays respectively). You then just need to populate it. You could do that with a loop:

```
String[] array = new String[length];
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    array[i] = "aa";
}
```

Or you could use the [`Arrays.fill`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) method:

```
String[] array = new String[length];
Arrays.fill(array, "aa");
```

One comment on your title though - it's worth understanding that once you've created an array, you can't actually add elements to it (or remove elements from it). The array object has a fixed size. If you do:

```
String[] array = new String[4];
...
array = new String[5];
```

then that doesn't add an element to the array - it creates a *new* array of length 5, and assigns a to that array to the variable `array`. Any other variables which still have a reference to the original array won't see any change.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this is what you want:

```
private String[] listView2 = new String[a];
for(int i = 0 ; i<a ; i++){
    listView2[i] = "aa";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An array has a set number of things it can contain.

If you want to have a dynamic list that can change size, then you should probably use `ArrayList<String>` like this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    list.add("aa");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike arrays in other languages, eg javascript, java arrays are fixed length.

If you want to add another element to a full array, you must create another larger array, copy the elements over and assign the end element.

Don't use arrays! They are a pain. Instead use a List, which will expand in size automatically when needed.